# Is dispatch needed in an action in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I've been learning redux for some time now and was wondering why is the dispatch needed in an action, cant we just use return, is that not the same thing?

```
  return {
    type: SEARCH_MOVIE,
    payload: text,
  };
};

export const fetchMovies = (text) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .get(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${APIKey}&s=${text}`)
    .then((response) =>
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_MOVIES,
        payload: response.data.Search,
      })
    );
};
```

The first action is without the dispatch and its working normally, why do we need to use dispatch in the other function cant we just use return? **I just need someone to explain to me what dispatch does inside an action that im gonna dispatch anyway later in my component somehow or onClick**.Why do we need to dispatch it twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) when using the [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) library.

> With a plain basic Redux store, you can only do simple synchronous updates by dispatching an action. ...
>
> Thunks are the recommended middleware for basic Redux side effects logic, including ... simple async logic like AJAX requests.

- **action**, in the redux vocabulary, is just an object, e.g. 
   `{type: 'a1'}`,
- **action creator** is a function that returns an action, e.g. 
  `(value) => ({type: 'a1', valye})`
- **thunk of action** is a function that takes dispatch function as an argument and calls it, e.g. 
  `(dispatch) => { dispatch({type: 'a1'}) }`. With the redux-thunk middleware, it can be used in any place where action is expected.
- **thunk of action creator** is a function (a) that returns a function (b) so that (b) is a *thunk of action* crated within a closure of (a), e.g. 
  `(value) => (dispatch) => { dispatch({type: 'a1', value}) }`

When using redux-thunk, the simple *action creator* and the *thunk of an action creator* can be used interchangeably, you don't have to use `(dispatch) => ...` when not needed (it is needed for asynchronous operations or more complex logic with multiple actions dispatched from one function).

Comment: So when i use dispatch inside of an action thats gonna get dispatched later anyway is where thunk comes into place and makes it work right?

Idk if im getting this right but is it when i use dispatch inside an action i just dispatch to get the data from the api so the data from the api is "stored" in that action that i can later dispatch and do whatever with that date, i might be really dumb but i need someone to explain it to me so i could understand it tho.

Comment: I added a definition of "action creator thunk", hope that will clarify what is what. There is no "dispatch inside an action", there are only more layers of abstraction on top of a simple action so that you can dispatch multiple actions asynchronously from a single function...

Comment: Is there any specific occasions where using dispatch inside of an action creator is a MUST or is it fine if i just use return everywhere.I'm really not understanding this stuff and why dispatch is even appearing in action creators.I just understand that dispatch() is used to send an action to a reducer, and thats why im wondering why is dispatch even appearing in an action creator(what are we dispatching from there? isnt it the same as return? why are we even using dispatch? etc..)(im just really confused with all of this stuff).

Comment: aaah, sorry, I realized I missed 1 step in my explanation - now updated with *thunk of action* vs. *thunk of action creator*... I guess it's much easier to use than to explain  it is **NOT a MUST**, you don't have to use dispatch inside an action creator - all action creators work as in simple redux + you have an option to replace any simple action with a `thunk of an action` thanks to the redux-thunk middleware

Comment: well ill probably understand it as the time goes by but anyway thank you so much for your effort cya